# ViewPager not inflating Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm using `ViewPager2`, `FragmentStateAdapter` and `TabLayout` to create a tabbed layout. My TabLayout and ViewPager2 are in a Fragment and the adapter has a list of two more fragments for the tabs. `OnCreateView` for each of the fragments is never called when I used the debugger or in log statements. `createFragment` is never called in the tab adapter either

**MainTabHolderFragment : Fragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val tabAdapter = TabAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
    tabAdapter.addFragment(AddItemFragment(), "Add Item")
    tabAdapter.addFragment(WishListFragment(), "Wish List")

    binding.viewPager.adapter = tabAdapter
    TabLayoutMediator(
        binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager,
        TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabAdapter.getPageTitle(position)
            Timber.d("tab = ${tab.position}, pos = $position")
            binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true)
        }).attach()
}
```

**TabAdapter**

```
class TabAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    private val fragmentList = mutableListOf<FragmentListItem>()

    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = fragmentList[position].fragment

    override fun getItemCount() = fragmentList.size

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        fragmentList.add(FragmentListItem(fragment, title))
    }

    fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? = fragmentList[position].title


    private data class FragmentListItem(val fragment: Fragment, val title: String)
}
```

The `tab.postion` variable in TabLayoutMediator is always -1, and the ViewPager never inflates the fragments, resulting in a blank screen under the tab layout. Do I need to use something other than `TabLayoutMediator` or `FragmentStateAdapter`?

EDIT: Added info stating `createFragment` not called

Answer (score 0):

My advice is change the TabAdapterConstructor using only the Fragment param and use as the next approach from my personal project:

```
class YourAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    private lateinit var yourList: List<YourListType>

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = yourList.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment =
        YourFragment.instance(yourList[position]) // Only is needed to pass data

    fun setList(yourList: List<YourListType>) {
        this.yourList = yourList
    }
}
```

And the ViewPager set in the main fragment:

```
view_pager.adapter = YourAdapter(this).apply{ 
    setList(yourList) 
}
```

And the method to init the Fragment:

```
companion object {
        private const val KEY_YOUR_OBJECT = "KEY_YOUR_OBJECT"

        fun instance(yourObject: YourObject): YourFragment {
            val arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putSerializable(KEY_YOUR_OBJECT, yourObject)
            }

            return YourFragment().apply {
                this.arguments = arguments
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Unfortuanately createFragment is never called, so this doesn't seem like the solution. With the `instance` method of the fragment, is that your own implementation using the singleton pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It´s too easy, add this.. (INSIDE OF ONCREATEVIEW)

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsID);

    tabsID.addTab(tabsID.newTab().setText("Fragment1"));
    tabsID.addTab(tabsID.newTab().setText("Fragment2"));
```

Now you already have tablayout with names, now create method (OUTSIDE OF ONCREATEVIEW), YOU WILL HAVE TO CREATE ONE FOR EACH TABITEM

```
public void homeScreen () {
    homeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2, homeInformation) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_item, parent, false);
            }

            Random rand = new Random();
            int random_number_home = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

            TextView number_home_list  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number_home_list);
            TextView textViewHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);
            textViewHome.setText(homeInformation[position]);
            number_home_list.setText(Integer.toString(random_number_home));
            return convertView;
        }
    };
    homeList.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
}
```

this code show your listview with random numbers, now this code is for select differents tabs.... the firts homescreen is the first that you see when you enter in app (INSIDE OF ONCREATEVIEW)

```
homeScreen();

    final TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener eventChangeTab = new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getText().toString().equals("Resumen")) {
                homeScreen();
            } else if (tab.getText().toString().equals("Datos Abonado")) {
                receiptsScreen();
            } 
        }


        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getText().toString().equals("Fragment1")) {
                homeScreen();
            } else if (tab.getText().toString().equals("Fragment2")) {
                receiptsScreen();
            } 
        }
    };

    tabsID.addOnTabSelectedListener(eventChangeTab );
```

Comment: What is the type of this `homeList`? I am using separate fragments for each page of the viewpager, not one ListView that gets rewritten. Thank you for your help but it doesn't seem to be for my issue

Comment: ListView homelist; (outside oncreateview) and homelist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_Home); (Inside oncreateview) -->list_Home is the listview ID in the XML

Comment: if you have 3 tabs you have to create 3 fragment, if you want to show diferents things just in one fragment is different,